# Variance of variable changes when I write to dataframe and read

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I obtain an aggregate dataframe by concatenating several other dataframe. However, I notice a really weird thing happen to me.
When I directly do a model fit on this aggregate dataframe, my R^2 is lower.

This is a huge problem because somehow my R^2 goes up by 10% (!!) when I dump my aggregated dataframe to a csv file and read from it. I notice that the variance of my Y variable is changing whenver I do this. I tried assert np.allclose which showed that my original copy and the copy read from the dataframe to all be close.

I think my variance somehow changes by quite a bit.

The dataframe has millions of rows too, which makes this all the more baffling. Surely precision issues cannot modify my R^2 by that much right.

Comment: Most likely this has to do with the string representation of the floating point numbers. You may be writing out less digits than you have in memory.

Comment: It is entirely possible that small changes in precision can have significant effects on results from calculations. There is an entire mathematical theory built around studying this effect.